# HTML password validation

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I have a page that has a field and a button.
I need that if the input equals a pre-defined password then it will reveal some text on the screen.
I'm not an html expert that's why ask this here.
In the meanwhile I have only this for now ...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8">
<title>Welcome</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="wrapper">
    <a rel="tooltip" align = "center" class="btn-success\" href="#"></a>
    <form>
        <input type="text" />
        <input type="submit" />
    </form>
  </div>


</body>
</html>
```

Thanks!

EDIT:
I would also like to ask for an PHP more secure solution.
Thanks!

Comment: You cannot do this with HTML alone. Javascript would do it, but coding a security restriction in Javascript client-side is completely pointless. So you need some server-side language here, and with that we cannot help you since there's an infinite number of choices.

Comment: **NEVER EVER** do password validation on client side. Use a server side script to do that (PHP, ASP.NET, ...). Validating passwords on client side is a **HUGE** security leak

Comment: find suitable answer from this.....      https://www.google.co.in/search?q=html+code+to+check+password&oq=html+pasword+chec&aqs=chrome.3.69i57j0l5.11176j0j7&sourceid=chrome&espv=210&es_sm=93&ie=UTF-8

Comment: Thanks for the help guys. This site of mine is actually just a demonstration so security matters aren't a real deal here. all tough I'd like to see some examples of yours, because I'm completely blacked out here. Thanks!

Comment: to avert from more negative voting i advise to close this question...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See [**THIS FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/PH66C/2/). I wont cover the same points made elsewhere concerning best practice and server side validation- these should have been made clear by now.

Type myValue in the textbox to see the hidden text.

jQ

```
$('input[type=text]').keyup(function () {
    $(this).val() == 'myValue' ? $('span').show() : $('span').hide();
});
```

HTML

```
<input type="text" />
<span>Hidden Text</span>
```

CSS

```
span{
    display:none;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

**Use a server-side language for this. For example PHP. Doing something like this in HTML is completely wrong. Do not use JavaScript for secure operations - it is viewable/editable on the client's side.**

However if you insist(you shouldn't!) you can do it with JavaScript:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8">
<title>Welcome</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="wrapper">
    <a rel="tooltip" align = "center" class="btn-success\" href="#"></a>
    <form onsubmit="checkPassword()">
        <input type="text" name="passwd"/>
        <input type="submit" />
    </form>
  </div>

<script type="text/javascript">

    function checkPassword(){
        if(document.getElementByName('passwd').value == "topSecretPassword"){
            alert("Good!");
        }else{
            alert("Bad :(");
        }
    }

</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a combination of HTML and Javascript to do what you want. Change your input boxes to

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function validate(){
        if(document.getElementById("my-field").value == "password"){
            document.getElementById("my-div").style.display = "block";
</script>

<input type="text" id="my-field" />
<button onclick="validate();">Submit</button>

<div id="my-div">Some hidden text here.</div>
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you're a beginner and you're just trying some examples so try the following code, but let me tell you NEVER check passwords with javascript NEVER NEVER!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8">
<title>Welcome</title>
</head>
<script>
var preDefinedWord = "test123";
function checkMyWord()
{
    if(document.getElementById("myword").value == preDefinedWord)
    {
       alert("its the same");
    }
    else
    {
      alert("not the same");
    }
}
</Script>
<body>
  <div id="wrapper">
    <a rel="tooltip" align = "center" class="btn-success\" href="#"></a>
    <form>
        <input id="myword" type="text" />
        <input onclick="checkMyWord()" type="button" />
    </form>
  </div>


</body>
</html>
```